# Add default text in textfield with follow of user typing value

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitextfield

I have one textfield.Where user will enter some name .But i want to keep some default text in my textfield followed by user typed values.

Like below :

```
usertypetextwillcomehere ##samsn
```

So, the `##samsn` will be the default text have to be in textfield. And the `usertypetextwillcomehere` will show the user typed value....in text field. If user type 2 letters also it have to show next to that two letter.Like below :

```
he ##samsn

h ##samsn

seconstextwillgere ##samsn
```

Its should follow with what ever user type value..Any idea that will be helpfull thanks

Comment: my answer did help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this UITextField subclass, configure your postfix, and enjoy

## improved

```
    class PostFixTextField: UITextField {
    
    @IBInspectable var postfix : String = ""
    @IBInspectable var removePostfixOnEditing : Bool = true
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textHasChanged), for: .editingDidEnd)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(removePostFix), for: .editingDidBegin)
        self.addTarget(self, action: #selector(textHasChanged), for: .editingChanged)
    }
    
    func textHasChanged()
    {
        self.removePostFix()
        self.addPostFix()
        self.setCursorPosition(input: self, position: (self.originalText()?.characters.count)!)
    }
    
    private func setCursorPosition(input: UITextField, position: Int) {
        let position = input.position(from: input.beginningOfDocument, offset: position)!
        input.selectedTextRange = input.textRange(from: position, to: position)
    }
    
    func addPostFix()
    {
        if(self.text != nil)
        {
        self.text = self.text! + postfix
        }
    }
    
    func originalText() ->String?{
        let prefixRange = NSString(string: (self.attributedText?.string)!).range(of: postfix)
        if(prefixRange.location != NSNotFound)
        {
            return self.text!.replacingOccurrences(of: postfix, with: "")
        }
        return self.text
    }
    
    func removePostFix(){
        
        if(self.removePostfixOnEditing && self.text != nil)
        {
            self.text = self.originalText()
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: sorry for late replay....no, actulayy i am using some other class for my textfield. So how can i use this textfield class to mine

Comment: @doubtman i think that you can use the same way but subclassing your custom TextField, try and let me know

Comment: Hi any solution for here ...https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45605670/google-analytics-ecommerce-value-is-not-updating-in-google-analytics-console

Answer (score 0):

You could put a label behind the text field and make the text field's background transparent. When the text field value updates, you can update the label's text with ##samsn added to the end. If you get the font and size exactly the same it will look like it's part of the text field.

Comment: but it have to follow with my entered vlaue in text field know...say if i enter more than 20 letters still it have to be last of my entered values followed by `##samsn`