# Google analytics Ecommerce value is not updating in google analytics console

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, google-analytics

I am doing the google analytics e-commerce tracking. And when I do any product shipping or any transaction.That value is not updating in my google analytics console.

Here my code :

```
   static func sendGAEvent(_ categoty: String, params: [String : NSObject]){

        let tracker = GAI.sharedInstance().tracker(withTrackingId: UA 234234-4)

        if let tracker = tracker {

            for (k, _) in params{
                let key = k
                let value = params[k]
                if let val = value as? String {
                    tracker.set(key, value: val)
                }
            }

            if let screenTitle = params[“screen_title” as? String{

                tracker.set(kGAIScreenName, value: screenTitle)

                guard let builder = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createEvent(withCategory: categoty, action: screenTitle, label: screenTitle, value: 0)
                    else
                {
                    return
                }



                tracker.send(builder.build() as [NSObject:AnyObject])

            }


            if  categoty ==  “shoping_cart”{

                let Tid  = params[mob_no] as? String
                let TRevenue  = params[amount] as? String    //  it will be amount of product getting from params
                let TCurrencyCode  = params[code] as? String   //  it will be code of product  from params

                tracker.set(kGAITransactionId, value: Tid)
                tracker.set(kGAITransactionRevenue, value: TRevenue)  
                tracker.set(kGAICurrencyCode, value: TCurrencyCode)

                guard let maker = GAIDictionaryBuilder.createTransaction(withId: Tid, affiliation: optional, revenue: 80, tax: 0, shipping: 0, currencyCode: TCurrencyCode)
                    else
                {
                    return
                }


                   print("done updating first")     
                tracker.send(maker.build() as [NSObject:AnyObject])
                print("done updating second")


            }



        }

    }
```

If any expert in google analytics please, give me some solution..!!

Thanks !

Comment: You are sending others GA events in this project and work?

Comment: @ Reinier Melian i din get. Can u please exaplain what i need to change  ?

Comment: i am sending the screen events also.so this is seperate..i will post my full code now

Comment: @ Reinier Melian  i have updated my code

Comment: Your tracking for screens its working?

Comment: @Reinier Melian  yes, its working..

Comment: ok, i will review this

Comment: yes please, for last one day i am hitting my head, dont knwo what wrong with this

Comment: I have tried to make one build..but that also not updating values in console.

Comment: @Reinier Melian  one small update...in my GA Its showing how much transaction i did like 4. But not showing the revenue value....ist still $0

Comment: @Reinier Melian  the way i am seing the revenune, tax, shipping values is correct ?

Comment: @Reinier Melian   any solution  ??

Comment: I don't see why this is failing, really

Comment: the way what i did is correct ?